# Open text file in android

Tags: android

On click on any txt file in any third party explorer (Es file explorer, Astro FM, etc), its showing a popupmenu, which contain the options to open that file. I implemented that as follows,

```
   gdview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int index, long arg3) 
        {
            final String options[] = {"Text", "Audio", "Video", "Image", "Other"};
            String selectedpath = filespath.get(index);
            File tmp = new File(selectedpath);
            if(tmp.isDirectory())
            {
                Intent intnt = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ChildAvtivity.class);
                intnt.putExtra(EXTRA_PATH, selectedpath);
                startActivity(intnt);
            }
            else
            {
                final Intent intent = new Intent();
                intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                final File file = new File(selectedpath);

                final MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
                final String ext=file.getName().substring(file.getName().indexOf(".")+1);
                final String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
                intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file),type);
                 startActivity(intent); 
              }
        }
 });
```

But now i want to and one more option (like my explorer) in that popupmenu. How to do that ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to add our own option to "Complete action using" menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18956232/how-to-add-our-own-option-to-complete-action-using-menu)

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your application to listen for Intents with [ACTION_VIEW](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_VIEW) in your application's manifest. 
You can set the file types to listen for using the `<data>` tag in the `<intent-filter>`.

This is detailed in the developer documentation in [Allowing Other Apps to Start Your Activity](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html).

For example, your manifest might look something like this:

```
<activity android:name="MyTextViewerActivity">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```