# How to add our own option to "Complete action using" menu

Tags: android

I want to run my app from "Complete action using" popup menu.I created a small app which is "file editor". When i click on any txt file in any filemanager i want my app also in "Complete action using " popmp menu.!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an intent filter to your Android.manifest.

This is in the documentation here:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/filters.html

Comment: <intent-filter>  
              <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />  

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />  
           
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND"/>  
          <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>  
          <data android:mimeType="text/plain"/>  
          <data android:mimeType="image/*"/>  
                
                </intent-filter>

Comment: This is the answer to your question. If you have a crashing app then you should ask a new question and post the relevant details such as logcat.